# How to set up DNS in 16.04 whithout using network-manager

Tags: network-manager, dns

I have tried add den-nameservers 114.114.114.114 and modify "/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.cong"  #dns=dnsmasq but after reboot , the "/etc/resolv.conf"  still

- nameserver 192.168.2.1    nameserver 192.168.2.1
  And i can't find the directory of "/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/" in my system, so im not sure modify "/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base" is useful 
  And I remove network-maneger, then modify
  "/etc/resolv.conf"
- nameserver 144.114.114.114

but when I reboot, "/etc/resolv.conf" still

- nameserver 192.168.2.1   nameserver 192.168.2.1

  This confused me, what is generated /etc/resolv.conf when reboot
  and how can i set a DNS without using network-manager??

Answer (score 0):

If you remove Network Manager, then, in 16.04, the usual way to configure networking is in the file `/etc/network/interfaces`. You file will look approximately like:

```
auto lo
inet lo iface loopback

auto enp3s0
inet enp3s0 inet static
address 192.168.1.150
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 144.114.114.114
```

Of course, substitute your exact details here.

If you prefer DHCP, then:

```
auto lo
inet lo iface loopback

auto enp3s0
inet enp3s0 inet dhcp
dns-nameservers 144.114.114.114
```

Reboot.

**EDIT**: It appears that you may have an issue with resolvconf. Please run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

Use the TAB key to accept the offer to reconfigure. Reboot.

Any improvement?

Comment: No matter i remove the network-manager or not, the "/etc/resolv.conf" still change to 192.168.2.1 and here is my /etc/network/interfaces

Comment: # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
# source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

#The loopback network interface 
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback 

#The primary network interface 
auto  eth0
iface eth0 inet static 
 address 192.168.18.226
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 network 192.168.18.0
 broadcast 192.168.18.255
 gateway 192.168.18.1
 dns-nameservers 211.138.151.161 211.138.55.66

Comment: I neither recommended, nor do you need, the broadcast and network entries. Please see my edit above in a few moments.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Here is my /etc/network/interfaces

```
  # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
  # Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
  # source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

  source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

  #The loopback network interface 
  auto lo
  iface lo inet loopback 

  #The primary network interface 
  auto  eth0
  iface eth0 inet static 
   address 192.168.18.226
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   network 192.168.18.0
   broadcast 192.168.18.255
   gateway 192.168.18.1
   dns-nameservers 211.138.151.161 211.138.55.66
```